# Finding patterns using Regex and replacing them with processed data

Tags: java, regex

There are input strings of the format

> ${ENC}:**107ec5141234742beec5cb5b1917e2e6**:{ENC}$${ENC}:**d0b2ddf0b9e7b397558c20c6232‌**​37c4f:{ENC}$${ENC}:**85d6f3cd7dcc5c67cad68ae45a0d5afc**:{ENC}$${ENC}:**5c0dfb55a843f830‌​024df0d74993b668**:{ENC}$

As you can see, the data ( in bold), are prefixed with **${ENC}:** and suffixed with **:{ENC}$**. And i want to replace all the Strings in between them with processed data.

I am using the Regular Expression:

```
\$\{ENC\}\:(.*?)\:\{ENC\}\$
```

which after escaping for java:

```
\\$\\{ENC\\}\\:(.*?)\\:\\{ENC\\}\\$
```

to find the matches and replace the Strings.

My code sample is below:

```
String THE_REGEX = "\\$\\{ENC\\}\\:(.*?)\\:\\{ENC\\}\\$";
Pattern THE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(THE_REGEX);

public static boolean isProcessingRequired(String data){
      if(data == null){
          return false;
      }

      return data.matches(THE_REGEX);
}


public String getProcessedString(String dataString){


    Matcher matcher = THE_PATTERN.matcher(dataString);
    if(matcher.matches()){

        String processedData = null;
        String dataItem = matcher.group(1);
        String procItem =  doSomeProcessing(dataItem);

        processedData = dataString.replaceAll("\\$\\{ENC\\}:" + encData + ":\\{ENC\\}\\$", procItem);

        if(isProcessingRequired(processedData)){
            processedData = getProcessedString(processedData);
        }

        return processedData;
    } else {
        return dataString;
    }
}

public String doSomeProcessing(String str){

     // do some processing on the string
     // for now:
       str = "DONE PROCESSING!!"

     return str;

}
```

But at `matcher.group(1)`, I'm getting

> `107ec5141234742beec5cb5b1917e2e6:ENC}$${ENC}:d0b2ddf0b9e7b397558c20c623237c4f:{ENC}$${ENC}:85d6f3cd7dcc5c67cad68ae45a0d5afc:{ENC}$${ENC}:5c0dfb55a843f830024df0d74993b668`

instead of

```
107ec5141234742beec5cb5b1917e2e6
```

which I was expecting.

I'm using the ? in regex to avoid this problem.
And when I tried it at the www.regexe.com, regex appears to be fine

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your first group is finished by `:ENC}$`, not `:{ENC}$`.

Comment: I guess example input as simple as `${ENC}:1:{ENC}$${ENC}:2:{ENC}$` would be enough to illustrate your problem

Comment: Sorry, my input String is ${ENC}:107ec5141234742beec5cb5b1917e2e6:{ENC}$${ENC}:d0b2ddf0b9e7b397558c20c623237c4f:{ENC}$${ENC}:85d6f3cd7dcc5c67cad68ae45a0d5afc:{ENC}$${ENC}:5c0dfb55a843f830024df0d74993b668:{ENC}$                  It was a typo. Can't find an option to edit my question :(

Comment: @1ujn4s edit link is under your question

Comment: [MCVE link](http://ideone.com/zKaKZs) for those interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [`Matcher.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) instead of [`Matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

From the javadoc:

> `public boolean matches()`
>
> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

---

> `public boolean find()`
>
> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

Here is a simple code expliciting the difference :

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\Q${ENC}\\E(.*?)\\Q{ENC}$\\E").matcher("${ENC}1{ENC}$${ENC}2{ENC}$");

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // Will print "1{ENC}$${ENC}2"
}

matcher.reset();

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // Will print "1"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Changing matcher.matches() to matcher.find() fixed the problem.